# infopath 2013 permission error

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have a few new computers ( not users) running windows 8.1 and InfoPath 2013. when they try to open a document they get " you do not have permission to open this document or the document is opened by another user. would you like to open in read only?" If you say yes it opens the doc as expected 9 I n read only mode).
However, if the user goes to a pc running InfoPath 2010 they are able to open and access the documents as normal.

What could be the problem with InfoPath 2013?

Any insight is greatly appreciated